# Two NIC must for RRAS VPN/NAT Server??

Tags: vpn, nat, rras

I am having one Server "windows server 2012 r2" with single NIC

I have few client outside my network So,

I need to configure RRAS server with VPN/NAT for remote client

Does RRAS server required two NIC to work with VPN/NAT??? if YES can anyone Please explain why?

Or can i work with single NIC??

It will be very appreciated if i got any simple explanation

Thanks in advance,
Nihal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NAT needs to be able to translate traffic coming from a private interface to an IP address attached to a public interface. When you configure NAT you identify one interface as Public and one as Private. This would be difficult on a Server with a single NIC. If you are running 2012 R2 and if you have the correct sort of NOC you can create virtual interface and have the same effect but I do not know whether this is a supported approach.

my advice, add a 2nd NIC, it will make the configuration of NAT and the VPN much easier for you.

Comment: Dear Michael,

Thanks for your clear explanations

Just i configured RRAS server with Virtual Interface VPN is connected but traffic is not passing 

I can only able to ping the gateway ip 

can anyone tell me what did i missing?